# Can't Consume Messages When Using Kafka v.0.10.0.x

Tags: apache-kafka

I'm using kafka v.0.10.2 on my cluster.

I can produce message fine using v.0.8.x and v0.10.2

BUT when consuming messages using client v0.10.0.x I'm having errors below;

> WARN [ConsumerFetcherThread-console-consumer-myconsumer-0-1002], Error in fetch kafka.consumer.ConsumerFetcherThread$FetchRequest@16090d7a. Possible cause: java.nio.BufferUnderflowException (kafka.consumer.ConsumerFetcherThread)

ok,now my kafka.clien is v.0.8.x
but ihave a new problem

```
    6 15:07:13 WARN scheduler.TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0, hadoop11, executor 10): org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task failed while writing rows
        at org.apache.spark.internal.io.SparkHadoopWriter$.org$apache$spark$internal$io$SparkHadoopWriter$$executeTask(SparkHadoopWriter.scala:151)
        at org.apache.spark.internal.io.SparkHadoopWriter$$anonfun$3.apply(SparkHadoopWriter.scala:79)
        at org.apache.spark.internal.io.SparkHadoopWriter$$anonfun$3.apply(SparkHadoopWriter.scala:78)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:109)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:345)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: kafka.common.KafkaException: String exceeds the maximum size of 32767.
        at kafka.api.ApiUtils$.shortStringLength(ApiUtils.scala:73)
        at kafka.api.TopicData$.headerSize(FetchResponse.scala:107)
        at kafka.api.TopicData.<init>(FetchResponse.scala:113)
        at kafka.api.TopicData$.readFrom(FetchResponse.scala:103)
        at kafka.api.FetchResponse$$anonfun$4.apply(FetchResponse.scala:170)
        at kafka.api.FetchResponse$$anonfun$4.apply(FetchResponse.scala:169)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:241)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:241)
        at scala.collection.immutable.Range.foreach(Range.scala:160)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.flatMap(TraversableLike.scala:241)
        at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.flatMap(Traversable.scala:104)
        at kafka.api.FetchResponse$.readFrom(FetchResponse.scala:169)
        at kafka.consumer.SimpleConsumer.fetch(SimpleConsumer.scala:135)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaRDD$KafkaRDDIterator.fetchBatch(KafkaRDD.scala:196)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaRDD$KafkaRDDIterator.getNext(KafkaRDD.scala:212)
        at org.apache.spark.util.NextIterator.hasNext(NextIterator.scala:73)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$GroupedIterator.fill(Iterator.scala:1126)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$GroupedIterator.hasNext(Iterator.scala:1132)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:408)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:408)
        at org.apache.spark.internal.io.SparkHadoopWriter$$anonfun$4.apply(SparkHadoopWriter.scala:124)
        at org.apache.spark.internal.io.SparkHadoopWriter$$anonfun$4.apply(SparkHadoopWriter.scala:123)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinallyAndFailureCallbacks(Utils.scala:1411)
        at org.apache.spark.internal.io.SparkHadoopWriter$.org$apache$spark$internal$io$SparkHadoopWriter$$executeTask(SparkHadoopWriter.scala:135)
        ... 8 more
```

what show i do 
String exceeds the maximum size of 32767.

Comment: Please show a [mcve] of all configurations, code, and commands used

Comment: I am pretty sure that the best case is to use the same version of the client with the broker version

Comment: yes,  I agree with you, but the point is that the versions are inconsistent.

Comment: https://kafka.apache.org/0102/documentation.html says Version 0.10.2 brokers support 0.8.x and newer clients. But the error you have is usually happened by a mismatch version.

Comment: String exceeds the maximum size of 32767.what  should i do

Comment: how long is your topic name? it seems like your topic name size is greater than Short.MAX_VALUE

Answer (score 0):

Tell me about my final plan
I upgraded the version to 0.10.2